# create login in actionscript flash

Tags: flash, actionscript

I am trying to create a flash file which has 3 games to be played over a weeks time, now my problem is,

I can make all 3 games in it but the client is asking each time a user opens the flash file it asks to login and it should remember the progress of my games of that particular user and then at the end of week publish the scores on a server I just don't know how to achieve this,

Do I need php or can this be done in flash itself, I am roughly thinking that all this can be saved in variables but wont the variables refresh once 
I open and close the file and wont store the values forever in it I am super confused any help appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Most common approach to solve this problem is keeping users' data on server side. In short, you need to create user interface on flash side, which will send information through URLRequest to your server side, where you should validate is log pass right and then make response to flash.
I've found good tutorial about, how to connect flash, php and mysql (to hold info about users) together.
[code.tutsplus.com](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-a-flash-login-system-using-php-and-mysql-part-1--active-5147)